# Which citizenship can I get without giving up my US citizenship?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, citizenship, dual-citizenship

I ask because I was born in the US and am a US citizen. However, if I want to move to another country I don't want to give up my US citizenship. If I move, I want to pick a country where I can have dual citizenship.

Comment: This question is borderline too broad. There are probably dozens of countries where you can naturalize while retaining your US citizenship. Do you really want a list of all of them?

Comment: The Wikipedia page on [Multiple citizenship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_citizenship) has a ton of information on this.

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks yes it does, and I've read it. It's convoluted, and never says, "here's a list of all the countries that allow dual citizenships." Can anyone at least provide a link to a _clear list_ of countries?

Comment: Here is a webpage that may have the information you need. http://www.multiplecitizenship.com/worldsummary.html I can't vouch for the accuracy of the information. I'm pretty sure I've seen a kind of synopsis of nationality laws by country from an official source before, but now I can't remember where.

Comment: Also, "move to another country" doesn't necessarily mean you are required to take up citizenship of that country. For example, you could move to Australia as a permanent resident and never need to worry about multiple citizenships.

Comment: @magnetar: Because there is no such thing as "allow" or "not allow" dual nationality -- as long as multiple countries' laws say you have their respective nationalities, you have multiple nationality. Each country only makes rules for the gain and loss of its own nationality. Some ways countries reduce multiple nationality include A) automatic loss of nationality upon naturalizing in a foreign country, or B) requiring renunciation of existing nationalities as a condition of naturalization. Many countries have rule B but not rule A; how do you categorize them?

Comment: @magnetar: And that doesn't even begin to get into the issue of nationalities at birth. Countries have various conditions for who automatically has the nationality at birth. But for every country on Earth, there are circumstances where under its law a person automatically has their nationality at birth, and also automatically has another country's nationality at birth. Some countries have loss of nationality at a certain age if other nationalities are not renounced, and some don't (including many countries with rules A and B above; how do you categorize them?). There are so many dimensions.

Comment: @user102008 multiple nationalities at birth, at least, are out of scope forthis question.

Comment: For your specific question here, what you really want to ask is, "What countries do not require renunciation of existing nationalities as a condition of naturalization?" since US nationality cannot be lost unless you voluntarily intend to relinquish it (which can usually only happen through explicit renunciation).

Comment: @phoog: I was trying to comment on the statement that the page "never says, "here's a list of all the countries that allow dual citizenships." "

Comment: @user102008 fair enough. As you note, there are many countries that in principle legislate against dual citizenship but nonetheless tolerate or even allow it in certain (possibly very limited) circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, you cannot lose your US citizenship unless you explicitly state *intent* to relinquish your citizenship. From [Advice about Possible Loss of U.S. Nationality and Dual Nationality](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal-considerations/us-citizenship-laws-policies/citizenship-and-dual-nationality.html):

> Section 349 of the INA ([8 U.S.C. 1481](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/uscode08/usc_sec_08_00001483----000-.html)), as amended, states that U.S. nationals are subject to loss of nationality if they perform certain *specified* acts *voluntarily* and *with the intention to relinquish* U.S. nationality.

It goes on to say that a consular officer will ask whether the person intends to relinquish U.S. nationality:

> If the answer to the question regarding intent to relinquish nationality is yes, the person concerned will be asked to complete a questionnaire to ascertain his or her intent toward U.S. nationality. When the questionnaire is completed and the voluntary relinquishment statement is signed, the consular officer will proceed to prepare a Certificate of Loss of Nationality of the United States.  The certificate will be forwarded to the Department of State for consideration and, if appropriate, approval.

This page makes it clear that the default position is that U.S. citizens do not intend to give up their U.S. citizenship. The only exceptions are when an individual:

> 1. formally renounces U.S. nationality before a consular officer;
> 2. serves in the armed forces of a foreign state engaged in hostilities with the United States;
> 3. takes a policy level position in a foreign state;
> 4. is convicted of treason.

You may acquire any other citizenship (according to the laws of the other country of course) without affecting your U.S. citizenship.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The question is what citizenships he can get without formally renouncing US citizenship.

Comment: @user102008: The answer to the question is "any of them", as stated above.

Comment: Greg, that's the answer as far as the US is concerned, but the US is not the only country with a say in the matter. The other country may require the US citizen to renounce US citizenship as a condition of naturalization. I believe this is why @user102008 posted that comment.

Comment: @phoog: If this question devolves into "list of countries that permit naturalization without requiring relinquishment of previous citizenships", then I would support closing it as too broad.

Comment: Hence my [comment](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10294/which-citizenship-can-i-get-without-giving-up-my-us-citizenship/10298?noredirect=1#comment17288_10294)!